# In-app Billing and GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-api-client

I had **great fun** implementing the *GoogleApiClient* for my game using [GameHelper.java](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java) I also want to use the Google billing services so I read the instructions at [developer.android.com..](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-service). Now I wonder why I can not find any code that uses a *GoogleApiClient* but code that uses a *ServiceConnection*. I thought that establishing the connection and handling all its cases is something that I already got with the *GoogleApiClient*. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-app billing service does not use `GoogleApiClient`. It is based on pure inter-process communication (IPC). I believe it's because in-app billing has been created before Google Play services. So you have to implement `ServiceConnection` callbacks.